# How to decode a json.stringify array in php without using explode function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I have a form with a `table`,`input[type=text]`and a `button[type=submit]`. If I click the submit button, it will assign the value of input field with the data from the table. I made the data from the table into a json form.  And I assign it like this in js:

```
document.getElementById("inputField").value =JSON.stringify(tb);
```

I want the value of the `inputField` to be in json form again inside the controller so that I can easily distribute the value. What I have in the controller is this:

```
$string =$this->input->post('inputField');
```

I entered the following values in my table

[image]

It gives me this output when I echo it:
[image]
But when I do `echo json_decode($this->input->post('inputField'));`, it gave $this error: **Array to string conversion**.
How to solve this?

EDIT:
When I do `print_r(json_decode($this->input->post('inputField')));`, it gave me this result:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [firstname] => Angelina [middlename] => Jolie [lastname] => Voight ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [firstname] => William [middlename] => Bradley [lastname] => Pitt ) )
```

Comment: post `json` string plese

Comment: **Don't use echo!** Do a `var_dump()` if you're unsure what type the variable is and `print_r()` if you know you're dealing with arrays/objects. `echo` is for strings only!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @**kingkero**

use

```
print_r(json_decode($this->input->post('inputField'), true));
```

or

```
var_dump(json_decode($this->input->post('inputField'), true));
```

without `true` it'll return an `object` and bu using `true` it'll give you an `associative array`

from `PHP Doc`

> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Comment: I mentioned a Thanks to you @kingkero :)

if you want your answer posted, I'll del mine one

Comment: I may have overreacted a bit. Maybe you can add a sentence on what `true` does